# Finding original datasets of clusters from K-means of unified dataset

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, k-means

I have two ndarrays `flattened_embeddings_d` and `flattened_embeddings_nd` that I want to run a K-means on and see how the clusters map out. I create a unified dataset of the two flattened embeddings concatenated and fit in the K-means.

```
embeddings_concat = np.concatenate((flattened_embeddings_d, flattened_embeddings_nd))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init=[d_means, nd_means]).fit(embeddings_concat)
```

I then get the labels and centroid positions like this:

```
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

# Plot clusters
plt.scatter(
    embeddings_concat[labels == 0, 0], embeddings_concat[labels == 0, 1],
    s=50, c='lightgreen',
    marker='s', edgecolor='black',
    label='cluster 1'
)

plt.scatter(
    embeddings_concat[labels == 1, 0], embeddings_concat[labels == 1, 1],
    s=50, c='orange',
    marker='o', edgecolor='black',
    label='cluster 2'
)
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1],
            s=150, color='red',
            marker='*', edgecolor='black')

plt.legend(scatterpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

This gets me two clusters with different color.
How do I now know which cluster belongs to `flattened_embeddings_d` and which one to `flattened_embeddings_nd`?

Comment: The labels for `flattened_embeddings_d` would be `labels[:flattened_embeddings_d.shape[0]]`, so you could use that to distinguish the clusters.

Comment: Would the label for `flattened_embeddings_nd` then be `ND_cluster = labels[:flattened_embeddings_nd.shape[0]]`? The cluster for D gives me an array with mostly 1's and a few 0's (about 6 percent is a 0), but when I calculate the ND cluster in the same way, it also gives me lots of 1's with about 6% of 0's. Shouldn't this be segregated more clearly?

Comment: ... only if the partition was perfect.  I don't know what your dataset looks like, but 94% accuracy might not be too bad.  You could plot `flattened_embeddings_d` and `flattened_embeddings_nd` in different colors/styles with their class also using a different color/style/edgecolor/etc.  BTW, wouldn't `ND_cluster` be `labels[flattened_embeddings_d.shape[0]:]`?

Comment: Indeed 94% accuracy is not bad, but I meant that the problem is that almost all of the labels are label 1, regardless of `flattened_embeddings_d` or `flattened_embeddings_nd`. When I check the labels, for both categories almost 94% precent is label 1. So my question is: am I doing something wrong here is or the data just poorly separable? (Yes, `ND_cluster` would be `labels[flattened_embeddings_d.shape[0]:]`, my bad)

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like.  Does there appear to be that much overlap between the two embeddings?

Comment: I would seem so, maybe that is the problem, thanks anyway!